# Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? during deployment of huge number of contracts

Tags: web3js, contract-deployment, nodejs, ganache

I am trying to deploy very large number of contracts (**more than 300 thousands**) with automine option at Ganache GUI .. Is it possible to do such experiments ? when i want to deploy such huge number of contracts, then i am facing following error;

```
Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully synced.
    at ABICoder.decodeParameters (C:\Users\aa\node_modules\web3-eth-abi\src\index.js:226:15)
    at extractingParams (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy - NewfromsFuzz.js:185:42)
    at main (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy - NewfromsFuzz.js:334:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\aa\Desktop\temp\deploy - NewfromsFuzz.js:381:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
(node:14280) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:14280) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**UPDATE**: here is my code

```
async function finalDeploy(r){

  for(i=0; i<constructorParams.length; i++) {

    const options = {
      data: '0x' + myBin[r]+constructorParams[i],
      gas: 5000000,
  };
  const signed = await web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(options, privateKey1);
  const receipt = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signed.rawTransaction);
  console.log("Contract: " +r+" is deployed at  " +receipt.contractAddress);
  contractAddressess.push(receipt.contractAddress)

  }

}
```

**note**: above code is valid to deploy 500+ smart contracts

**UPDATE 2:** Also it should be noted that i have **only one contract** and one **ABI**. but i am just trying to deploy that contract with millions different values for its constructor. That's why I am saying i want to deploy millions contract. 
For every contract, in my each `constructorParams` there is value like `0x00ff0040f5020000000000000000001d00000000000002ff37ff4a1f00000b00`. this value is encoded for my following constructor (and for every contract this is the same constructor) ...

```
  constructor(address _wallet) public payable {
        totalSupply = 6;
        owner = _wallet;
    }
```

As pointed out in comments that there may be some wrong value for your constructor. To answer this point; if i try my above code to deploy my contract with first 500 different values for constructor, then there is no problem.. but if i try the same code with 600 or above values, then at least first 500 values should deploy 500 contracts, but i have received above mentioned error without deploying even a single contract.

Comment: You don't seriously expect anyone to explain a given error without you posting the code which has triggered this error, do you?

Comment: oh... sorry .. forget to write code here.. see my update..

Comment: The `Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas?` error typically indicates that the abi-encoded data was not encoded correctly.

Comment: In "normal transactions" (i.e., function calls), it typically indicates that the encoded function (the value of the `data` field) does not exist in the target contract (pointed by the `to` field). It can also indicate that the encoded parameters (again - part of the `data` field) mismatch with what the contract's function expects to receive. In contract-deployment transactions (as seems to be your case), I am not quite sure what it means, but I'd take the liberty to guess that this (the value of the `data` field) is not a valid contract byte-code.

Comment: then why my code works for 500+ contracts... ?

Comment: Well, how about - you have the valid byte-code of 500+ contracts, and an invalid byte-code for 1 other contract...? You can verify this by changing the order of submissions (start with the byte-code whose deployment fails).

Comment: actually, these 300 thousand contracts are ... just one contract but with different parameters values.. means only one BYTECODE is there... which make this contract to million contracts...

Comment: I am trying to deploy same contract with different values

Comment: A simple conclusion would be that one of your values is incorrect (either in format, or in the fact that the contract asserts a specific range which this value falls out of).

Comment: Again, you can verify this by starting with the failed transaction. If it fails regardless of the order of transactions, then I would tend to think that you are using one or more illegal values (for this specific contract).

Comment: actually, the main problem is that if i give millions values then my code directly display above mentioned error.. without deploying any contract ... at least they should deploy right ones ....

Comment: I cannot find a reasonable alignment with your code and the statement "if i give millions values" (i.e., I cannot see how you can pass "millions values" to your function, assuming that's what you meant). Please rephrase your question. Also, please specify what each entry in the `constructorParams` array (or object) looks like. We're not supposed to guess that. Thanks.

Comment: see update 2, i have tried to clear... , if still some ambiguity then let me know

Comment: "but if i try the same code with 600 or above values, then at least first 500 values should deploy 500 contracts" - not clear. Is it 500? is it 600? What do you mean by "should"? When you increase to 600 then nothing works? What about increasing to 501?

Comment: The error indicates problem at function`extractingParams` from file `deploy - NewfromsFuzz.js` line 185.

Comment: yes, you are right... there are logical problem in my extracingParam function... thanks.. i am trying to remove it...